# Create a nnModule that's just the identity

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to debug a pretty complex interaction between different nnModules. It would be very helpful for me to be able to replace one of them with just an identity network for debugging purposes. For example:

```py
net_a = NetworkA()
net_b = NetworkB()
net_c = NetworkC()

input = Autograd.Variable(torch.rand(10,2))

out = net_a(input)
out = net_b(out)
out = net_c(out)
```

I would like to be able to just change the second line to `net_b = IdentityNet()`, instead of having to go through and reconnect all my As to Cs. But, when I make a completely empty nnModule, the optimizer throws `ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list`.

Is there any workaround this?

A minimum non-working example:

```py
import torch.optim as optim

class IdentityModule(nnModule):
    def forward(self, inputs):
        return inputs

identity = IdentityModule()
opt = optim.Adam(identity, lr=0.001)
out = identity(any_tensor)
error = torch.mean(out)
error.backward()
opt.step()
```

Comment: What do you mean by empty nnModule? What does your `IdentifyNet()` looks like? Does it simply return its input? You should make your post more clear.

Comment: Yes, I want the IdentityNet to return just its input. I figured I could make the `forward` method just return the input, but then the optimizer raises an error saying that there are no parameters to optimize.  I'm looking for advice on writing an IdentityNet class.

Comment: you should give an minimal working example for people to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter here is a logical one. Look at what it means when you do:

```py
error.backward()
opt.step()
```

`.backward()` will recursively compute the gradients from your output to any input you pass into the network. In terms of the computation graph, there are two noteworthy kinds of inputs: the input you pass in, and the `nn.Parameter`s that model the network's behavior. When you then do `opt.step()`, PyTorch will look for any input that it can update to change the output of the network, namely the `nn.Parameters()`.

However, your Pseudo-code *does not have a single `nn.Parameter`!*, since the identity module does not contain one. So when you call these functions, the `opt.step()` has no targets, explaining the error message.

This does not extend to the case you describe earlier. If you chain a module with no parameters into a larger chain with some that do have parameters, there are parameters to train in the computation graph.

You need to make sure, though, that the optimizer indeed gets all of these parameters passed upon initialization. A simple trick is to print these:

```py
net_a = SomeNetwork()
net_b = IdentityNetwork()  # has no parameters
net_c = SomeNetwork()

print(list(net_a.parameters()))  # will contain whatever parameters in net_a
print(list(net_b.parameters()))  # will be []
print(list(net_c.parameters()))  # will contain whatever parameters in net_c
# to train all of them, you can do one of two things:
# 1. create new module. This works, since `.parameters()` collects params recursively from all submodules. 
class NewNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.net_a = net_a
        self.net_b = identity
        self.net_c = net_c

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.net_c(self.net_b(self.net_a(input)))
all_parameters = list(NewNet().parameters())
print(all_parameters)  # will contain a list of all parameters of net_a and net_c

# 2. simply merge the lists
all_parameters = list(net_a.parameters()) + list(net_b.parameters()) + list(net_c.parameters())
print(all_parameters)  # will contain a list of all parameters of net_a and net_c


opt = optim.SGD(all_parameters)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm doing something GAN-like where I do not want all parameters to update every time, but I could do something with requires_grad=False to get around that. Good suggestion combining them into one network.

Comment: @SamBobel, why not use `detach()` for the intermediate variable?

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't seen `detatch` before

Answer (score 4):

You can also [just do](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9160#issuecomment-402381789):

```
net_b = torch.nn.Sequential()
```

EDIT: in PyTorch 1.7, `[nn.Identity](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Identity.html#torch.nn.Identity)` appeared. Doc is [here].

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of pytorch has an identity module [`nn.Identity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Identity.html#torch.nn.Identity).

```py
net_b = nn.Identity()
```